# Postgresql Error: could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer

Tags: nginx, postgresql, django, uwsgi

I try this stack: nginx + uwsgi + django + postgresql, the request can reach to views of django, client show `500 server internal fault`, I check postgres log, found the error `could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer`. How to debug this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause, in my uwsgi configuration file, I set `thread = 2`, after changing this to `master = true` and `processes = 4`, it works well now.

Well, how to debug this? I google [the error](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/678A67F9-394C-47CC-BE82-C5435DF0E762@artsman.com), which tells me this is not postgresql fault, client application dropped the connection to database, on this stack: `nignx <-> uwsgi <-> django <-> postgresql`, so maybe the cause hide in nginx, uwsgi or djagno, I check nginx log and uwsgi log, there are no error logged. My friend suggest me that use pycharm to debug django remotely, I did debug django in deployment server, django was ok. Then I check configuration of uwsgi, found a novice's fault...